# Counting events in a group_by manner (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

Here is my code:

```
set.seed(23)
data_toy <- tibble(
  family_code = sample(factor(400:410),1000,T),
  event_type = factor(sample(c("sad","happy"),1000,
                replace = TRUE,prob = c(.2,.8))),
  score = sample(1:100,1000,TRUE)
) %>% mutate(score = if_else(event_type =="happy",NA,score)) %>% 
  arrange(family_code)
```

Output:

```
family_code event_type score
   <fct>       <fct>      <int>
 1 400         happy         NA
 2 400         happy         NA
 3 400         happy         NA
 4 400         happy         NA
 5 400         sad           57
 6 400         happy         NA
 7 400         happy         NA
 8 400         happy         NA
 9 400         happy         NA
10 400         sad           65
```

I would like to create a feature that counts the number of happy events until a sad event for each family.

In the example I shared, my desired output would be:

```
family_code event_type score happy_counter
   <fct>       <fct>      <int>         <dbl>
 1 400         happy         NA            NA
 2 400         happy         NA            NA
 3 400         happy         NA            NA
 4 400         happy         NA            NA
 5 400         sad           57             4
 6 400         happy         NA            NA
 7 400         happy         NA            NA
 8 400         happy         NA            NA
 9 400         happy         NA            NA
10 400         sad           65             4
11 400         happy         NA            NA
12 400         happy         NA            NA
13 400         happy         NA            NA
14 400         happy         NA            NA
15 400         happy         NA            NA
16 400         happy         NA            NA
17 400         happy         NA            NA
18 400         happy         NA            NA
19 400         sad           79             8
20 400         sad           78             0
```

My data has approx. 10k observations. I tried `group_by` and `nest_by` but struggled with zeroing the count after each sad event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
out <- data_toy %>%
   group_by(family_code, ind = consecutive_id(event_type)) %>% 
   mutate(n = n()) %>% 
   slice_head(n = 1) %>%
   group_by(family_code) %>%
   mutate(n = lag(n) * NA^(event_type == "happy")) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(ind, family_code, event_type, happy_counter = n) %>%
   left_join(data_toy %>% 
   mutate(ind = consecutive_id(event_type)), .) %>% 
   group_by(family_code, ind) %>% 
   mutate(happy_counter = happy_counter * (all(event_type == "sad") & 
     !duplicated(happy_counter))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
head(out, 20)
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   family_code event_type score   ind happy_counter
   <fct>       <fct>      <int> <int>         <dbl>
 1 400         happy         NA     1            NA
 2 400         happy         NA     1            NA
 3 400         happy         NA     1            NA
 4 400         happy         NA     1            NA
 5 400         sad           57     2             4
 6 400         happy         NA     3            NA
 7 400         happy         NA     3            NA
 8 400         happy         NA     3            NA
 9 400         happy         NA     3            NA
10 400         sad           65     4             4
11 400         happy         NA     5            NA
12 400         happy         NA     5            NA
13 400         happy         NA     5            NA
14 400         happy         NA     5            NA
15 400         happy         NA     5            NA
16 400         happy         NA     5            NA
17 400         happy         NA     5            NA
18 400         happy         NA     5            NA
19 400         sad           79     6             8
20 400         sad           78     6             0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. your code worked. though seems a bit more complicated, the way you took advantge of lag and slice() is trully creative. THANK YOU

Comment: @RYann With a big data, I am not sure which one is the expected as I find difference in output between mine and the other solution

Comment: In quick sight both outputs looks similar. I tested it and indeed I got 6 FALSE results. Ill go right on it and will update my comment

Comment: @RYann By testing i get `all.equal(out$happy_counter, out1$happy_counter)
[1] "'is.NA' value mismatch: 801 in current 804 in target"`

Comment: Yep. I called Andre's not_out, and deselected you 'i' coloumn and there is a weird, appearing random, mismatch in indices 112 190 298 651 742 919 ## bad_indices <- which(out$happy_counter!=not_out$happy_counter)
view(cbind(not_out[bad_indices,],out[bad_indices,4]))

Comment: Thank you @akrun. It was lack of grouping by family. Alright. its reading documentation time for me. Thank you for such a quick solution, i struggled with this since the begining of the week

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, using `lag` to access the count value

```
library(dplyr)

data_toy %>% 
  group_by(grp = consecutive_id(event_type), family_code) %>% 
  mutate(is = sum(event_type == "happy")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(happy_counter = if_else(event_type == "sad", lag(is), NA)) %>% 
  select(-c(grp, is)) %>% 
  print(n = 21)
# A tibble: 1,000 × 4
   family_code event_type score happy_counter
   <fct>       <fct>      <int>         <int>
 1 400         happy         NA            NA
 2 400         happy         NA            NA
 3 400         happy         NA            NA
 4 400         happy         NA            NA
 5 400         sad           57             4
 6 400         happy         NA            NA
 7 400         happy         NA            NA
 8 400         happy         NA            NA
 9 400         happy         NA            NA
10 400         sad           65             4
11 400         happy         NA            NA
12 400         happy         NA            NA
13 400         happy         NA            NA
14 400         happy         NA            NA
15 400         happy         NA            NA
16 400         happy         NA            NA
17 400         happy         NA            NA
18 400         happy         NA            NA
19 400         sad           79             8
20 400         sad           78             0
21 400         happy         NA            NA
# … with 979 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks clean and simple and definetly does the trick. I will read more about consecutive_id. I didnt know that function. THANK YOU!

Comment: @RYann I think I forgot to also group by "family_code", added an edit.

Comment: You are right, that was the mistake @akrun payed attention to. thank you for correcting and providing you solution!